# Kafka "Login module not specified in JAAS config"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

I have a problem communicating with Kafka secured with `sasl` using console scripts. Kafka is secured with `sasl`, listener is `SASL_PLAINTEXT` and mechanism is `PLAIN`.

What I did:
I tried listing some data using one of kafka scripts:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server (address) --list
```

However I get

```
WARN Bootstrap broker (address) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

and command fails, which is understandable because it's secured with sasl.

So I tried how to add client username/password to that command.
First, I tried to run `kafka-console-consumer` script, I used `--command-config` to add necessary file. I quickly discovered that I can't add `jaas` file directly and I needed to use `.properties` file, so I did.

My properties file(keep in mind that brackets indicate "censored" data, I can't put all real data here):

```
bootstrap.servers=(address)
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
sasl.jaas.config=(path)/consumer_jaas.conf
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
group.id=(group)
```

My jaas file:

```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username=(username)
    password=(password);
};
```

This `jaas` file works in my standard java applications.

However, when I'm trying to run either `kafka-consumer-groups` script or `kafka-console-consumer`, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Login module not specified in JAAS config
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:94)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:51)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:84)
at kafka.admin.AdminClient$.create(AdminClient.scala:229)
at kafka.admin.AdminClient$.create(AdminClient.scala:223)
at kafka.admin.AdminClient$.create(AdminClient.scala:221)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.createAdminClient(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:454)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.<init>(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:389)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:65)
at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Login module not specified in JAAS config
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.<init>(JaasConfig.java:68)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.jaasConfig(JaasUtils.java:59)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:85)
```

This `jaas` file is a direct copy of a file that I'm using in java app that communicates with kafka and it works, however here, using console tools, it just doesn't work. I tried searching for a solution but I can't find anything useful.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are 2 ways to provide the JAAS configuration to the Kafka clients.

- Via the client property: `sasl.jaas.config`. In that case you set it to the actual JAAS configuration entry. For example, your configuration file becomes:

  ```
  bootstrap.servers=(address)
  zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
  zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
  sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="(username)" password="(password)";
  security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
  group.id=(group)
  ```

  As you've already figured out, you can use `--command-config` to pass a properties file to `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`.
- Via the Java property: `java.security.auth.login.config`. In this case, you set it to the path of your JAAS file. Also if you set it in `KAFKA_OPTS`, `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` will pick it up automatically.

  ```
  export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=(path)/consumer_jaas.conf"
  ```

Comment: I put jaas configuration entry directly into .properties file and it worked. Now I can use these scripts without any errors. I don't know why it had problems with external file. Thank you!

Comment: When using sasl.jaas.config, you can only set it to the JAAS configuration entry it doesn't work with the path to a file. On the contrary with the Java property, it only works with the path to a file.

Comment: I have set sasl.jaas.config properly, but I still get `[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand - Error while running kafka-ready.` and `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set`.  How do I make it stop looking for a .jaases file and instead just use what I've specified?