# Http request in Java to Hadoop Kerberized Cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, httpclient, kerberos

i need to send Http request to a Hadoop Cluster with Kerberos auth and i want to authenticate with a Keytab.
I found a library HttpClient by Apache and i wrote this code to get the HttpClient:

```
    private static CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    provider.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("YarnManager", "YarnManager")
    );
    return HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .build();
}
```

But i can only authenticate after doing Kinit command on my KeyTab.
How can i pass the path to my keytab in httpclient?
Do you know other libraries to do that?

Answer (score 1):

About Apache HttpClient: quoting [Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/web_and_rest.html) by Steve Loughran (from when he had to maintain `hadoop-auth` library)

> The Apache HTTP Client/http components have a well-deserved reputation
>   for being great libraries to work with remote HTTP servers.
>   Should you use them for Kerberos/SPNEGO authenticated applications?
>
> **No.**
>   *(...)*
>   Don't waste time or make things worse: go with the JDK libraries

---

About Kerberos auth over HTTP: the standard is to use **SPNego** which is implemented by every decent HTTP client in any language. And by any serious HTTP server or proxy, although the setup is more complicated server-side.

The problem about Java clients is that, [quoting Steve Lougran again](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html),

> the public Java APIs are brittle across versions and JDKs ... Releases within a Java version may break the internals and/or the public API's behaviour.

That may explain why the "native" Java HTTP client is more robust that the Apache one, when it comes to the Java implementation of Kerberos i.e. **JAAS** -- that's what you need to configure if you want to be able to use a keytab.

Now, the Java implementation of Kerberos is not only brittle, it's incomplete *(no way to write into the ticket cache, no way to create renewable tickets, etc)* and not well documented -- [quoting S.L. once more](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jaas.html)

> JAAS is a nightmare from the Enterprise Java Bean era, one which
>   surfaces from the depths to pull the unwary under 
> *(...)*
>   a single `jaas.conf` file can have multiple contexts ... Different contexts can have different login/auth mechanisms, including Kerberos and LDAP

Fun fact: actually a single context may define multiple mechanisms (1st entry is tried, if unsuccessful 2nd is tried etc) -- and for each mechanism, multiple ways to get credentials. See these posts for the syntax & for more reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507547/5162372
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776704/5162372

---

AFAIK the default JAAS behaviour for SPNego is *"look into the system cache (as defined by `$KRB5CCNAME` or by `/etc/krb5.conf` or by the hard-coded default); otherwise prompt for user/password unless the prompting is blocked by the JVM security policy (which is the default since the JVM cannot guess whether it needs an UI prompt or a console prompt)"*.

You will need to override that to create a private, in-memory ticket from a keytab; and also need some tweaks that are not really well documented -- cf. that post for example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42506620/5162372

The post above focuses on JDBC but also applies to SPNego with two caveats:

- the JAAS section must be labeled `com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate`
- there's an extra debug flag `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`

Also, that "tutorial" from Oracle does not cover the keytab option but may be useful for context:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a similar thing recently, but instead of Java, it was in C++.

There was no straightforward way to get around that. Doing a `kinit` was left as a responsibility of the user.